# re-bind keys highlight text in terminal

Tags: terminal, arrow-keys

I want re-bind keys on CentOS 8 to be able use combination Ctrl + Shift + arrow key to highlighted a text in terminal.
I found keybinding file in:

```
/etc/inputrc
```

Ctrl + Shift + arrow key is:

```
^[[1;6C
^[[1;6D
```

But I don't know what write in that file.

Normally when I use this combination I get in terminal "D" or "C". Could you give me a hint about that or this is even possible?

Comment: need to explain what your trying to accomplish. In terminal do you mean like directly on command line, in an editor like VIM etc.

Comment: Note that changes in `/etc/inputrc` may affect not only the `bash` shell, but also any other program that uses the `readline` library. Also, note that text highlighting for copy/paste operations between a terminal window and some other GUI application is not done by the shell, but by the terminal emulator: if you want to highlight text for copying to another window, you should look at configuring your terminal emulator's key bindings rather than the shell's.